# Identifier is too long while loading from SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE  acn_scr_upload_header
(
FILE_RECORD_DESCRIPTOR    varchar2(5)    NOT NULL,
schedule_no               Number(10)     NOT NULL,
upld_time_stamp           Date           NOT NULL,
seq_no                    number         NOT NULL,
filename            varchar2(100)  ,
schedule_date_time        Date      
);
```

When I try to load my file via SQL*Loader I'm getting an error on this value in the column filename: `Stock_Count_Request_01122014010101.csv`. The error is:

```
Error on table ACN_SCR_UPLOAD_HEADER, column FILENAME.  
ORA-00972: identifier is too long".
```

If I try to insert the same value into the table using an INSERT statement it works fine.

My data file Stock_Count_Request_01122014010101.csv looks like

```
FHEAD,1,12345,20141103
FDETL,7,100,W,20141231,SC100,B,N,1,5
FTAIL,8,6
```

and control file

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '$IN_DIR/$FILENAME'
APPEND
INTO TABLE ACN_SCR_UPLOAD_HEADER
WHEN FILE_RECORD_DESCRIPTOR = 'FHEAD'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
FILE_RECORD_DESCRIPTOR position(1),
LINE_NO FILLER,
schedule_no ,
schedule_date_time,
upld_time_stamp                sysdate,
seq_no  "TJX_STOCK_COUNT_REQ_UPLD_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
FILENAME     constant ""
)
```

Comment: What does your ctl file and your data look like? The failed record should be in a bad file somewhere. (that's the full record as the issue could easily be something like misplaced delimiters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the information and you're not putting any data into the filename there, so I'm confused how you got the value in your question.